# Number of spreadsheets in workbook in python

Tags: python, xlsx, win32com

how  to check the quantity of the  spreadsheets in xlsx workbook in python? Is there  any command  under  win32com library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a [mini cookbook](http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/) for working with win32com and excel.

For your particular question, the following should work:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('your excel file.xlsx')
print(len(wb.Worksheets))  # tells you how many worksheets
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks! by the way I already found  another way. it's  simple like wb.Worksheets.Count .   Anywayy thanks for  reply

Answer (score 3):

You can get the number of spreadsheets in a given workbook by using the popular xlrd module

```
import xlrd
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('sample.xlsx')
print len(workbook.sheet_names())
```

Update per @Gerrat

you can do this too

```
print workbook.nsheets
```

Comment: Or just `print workbook.nsheets` (from [here](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#xlrd.Book.nsheets-attribute))

Comment: Thanks  bob, but  it will work only with  xls files, not  xlsx.